# How to make nested foreach loop method generic

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I want to get a list of all (unique) Apple (or Oranges) objects:

```
var theBigFruitsList = new List<Fruits>{
    new Fruits(){
        Apples = new List<Apple>{
                new Apple { Id = 1 },
                new Apple { Id = 2 }
            }
        },
        Oranges = new List<Orange>{
                new Orange { Id = 4 },
                new Orange { Id = 5 }
            }
        },
        FruitBoolean = False,
        FruitCount = 4,
    },
    new Fruits(){
        Apples = new List<Apple>{
                new Apple { Id = 3 },
                new Apple { Id = 1 },
            }
        },
        Oranges = new List<Orange>{
                new Orange { Id = 6 },
            }
        }
        FruitBoolean = False,
        FruitCount = 3,
    }
}
```

I have written this method for it:

```
public static List<Apple> GetApplesFromBigFruitsList(List<Fruits> theBigFruitsList )
{
    var dc = new Dictionary<long, Apple>();
    foreach (var fruits in theBigFruitsList)
    {
        foreach (var apple in fruits.Apples)
        {
            if (!dc.ContainsKey(apple.Id))
                dc.Add(apple.Id, apple);
        }
    }
    return dc.Values.ToList();
}
```

But as besides Apples and Oranges there are many other types of 'Fruits' in that object, I have that method more then 10 times where the word Apple is just replaced with Orange.. It would make sense to make it generic.

I wrote this function but it gives an [error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1579) as Fruits class does not implement an enumerator. Please help!

```
    public static List<T> FilterFruits<T>(T typeToGet, List<Fruits> theBigFruitsList)
    {
        List<T> fruitResult = new List<T>();

        var fruitType = typeToGet.GetType();

        foreach (var fruits in theBigFruitsList)
        {
            foreach (var fruit in fruits) //errors, intention is to loop over all properties in the Fruits entity to find one specific type
                if (fruit.GetType() == fruitType) //check if type is Apple
                {
                    fruitResult.AddRange(fruits); //add the Apples to a list
                }
        }
        return fruitResult;
    }
```

The classes:

```
public class Fruits{
    public List<Apple> Apples { get; set; }
    public List<Orange> Oranges { get; set; }
    public List<Pineapple> Pineapples { get; set; }
    public List<Mango> Mangos { get; set; }
    public bool FruitBoolean { get; set; }
    public long FruitCount { get; set; }
    }
public class Apple{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
public class Orange{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}   
public class Pineapple{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}   
public class Mango{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

The desired method result:

```
var Apples = List<Apple>{
    new Apple { Id = 1 },
    new Apple { Id = 2 },
    new Apple { Id = 3 }
}
```

Comment: Please show the classes, `Fruits`, `BigFruitList`, `Apple`, `Orange`.

Comment: I've added the constructs of the classes. The `theBigFruitList` is a list holding `Fruits` objects.

Comment: And two more fruits. The `Apple` and other fruit classes hold more properties (differing per type of fruit) but I left them out for simplicity. They all have the `Id` propery in common.

Comment: @jonadv I think you're better off with an interface than with a generic. In addition, you could refactor your code so the fruit type becomes an enum VS a complex object by itself. This way you wouldn't even need a generic method for it.

Comment: The objects are large and have a lot of history, I can't change them unfortunately. However, all the fruit classes (`Apple`, `Orange`) do implement from the same interface. I run into the same problem though.

Answer (score 3):

### With One Big List

Storing each type of fruit in its own separate list is...weird. I suggest you combine them in a single list. If you can't change the design, you can combine them at run time like this:

```
IEnumerable<object> GetAllFruits(Fruits bigFruitlist)
{
    return ((IEnumerable<object>)bigFruitlist.Apples) 
    .Concat((IEnumerable<object>)bigFruitlist.Oranges) 
    .Concat((IEnumerable<object>)bigFruitlist.Mangoes) 
    .Concat((IEnumerable<object>)bigFruitlist.Pineapples); 
}
```

Of course it would be way better if all of your fruits had a common interface-- then you wouldn't need `IEnumerable<object>`-- but this can still work if you can't make that change either.

Once you have the combined list, the rest is easy:

```
List<T> FilterFruits<T>(Fruits bigFruitlist)
{
    return GetAllFruits(bigFruitList).OfType<T>().ToList();
}
```

### With an Array of Lists

If there is some reason you want to avoid enumerating all of the lists (i.e. the lists are massive and performance is a concern), you can also do it with an array of lists.

```
object[] GetAllFruitLists(Fruits bigFruitlist)
{
    return new object[]
    {
        bigFruitlist.Apples,
        bigFruitlist.Oranges,
        bigFruitlist.Mangoes, 
        bigFruitlist.Pineapples
    }; 
}

List<T> FilterFruits<T>(Fruits bigFruitlist)
{
    return GetAllFruitLists(bigFruitList).OfType<List<T>>().Single();
}
```

Comment: Yes. This. And since the OP mentioned in comments that there's a common interface to the fruits, you can replace `object` with that interface, and add generic constraints. To accommodate the need to find a single instance of each fruit, one can throw `.DistinctBy(f => f.Id)` on the results.

Comment: It gives compile error CS1061 on `((IEnumerable<object>)bigFruitlist.Apples)` as `theBigFruitList` is a List of `Fruits` and not a `Fruits` on itself. Adding .First() in between compiles, but thats not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To interrogate an object's type at runtime use Reflection.  Like this:

```
public static List<T> FilterFruits<T>(List<Fruits> fruitsList) where T : IFruit
{
    List<T> fruitResult = new List<T>();

    var fruitType = typeof(T);

    foreach (var fruits in fruitsList)
    {
        foreach (var fp in typeof(Fruits).GetProperties())
        {
            if (fp.PropertyType == typeof(List<T>)) //check if type is Apple
            {
                fruitResult.AddRange((List<T>)(object)fp.GetValue(fruits)); //add the Apples to a list
            }
        }
    }
    return fruitResult;
}
```

`(T)(object)o` is the C# idiom for performing a cast that can't by verified by the compiler, and may possibly fail at runtime, which we know that it won't but the compiler can't because it doesn't understand Reflection.

To do this without Reflection (which can be too slow for some scenarios), you can do something like this:

```
public static List<T> GetDistinct<T>( IEnumerable<Fruits> fruitsList) where T : IFruit
{
    var ft = typeof(T);
    Func<Fruits, List<T>> picker;

    if (ft == typeof(Apple))
    {
        picker = (fruits) => (List<T>)(object)fruits.Apples;
    }
    else if (ft == typeof(Mango))
    {
        picker = (fruits) => (List<T>)(object)fruits.Mangos;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException($"Fruit Type {ft.Name} not supported");
    }

    var rv = new Dictionary<long, T>();
    foreach (var t in fruitsList.SelectMany(picker))
    {
        if (!rv.ContainsKey(t.Id))
        {
            rv.Add(t.Id, t);
        }
    }

    return rv.Values.ToList();


}
```

Comment: Thank you, the first method is in initially what I was looking for. However, after implementation, reflection does not have preference. The other method gives compile error CS1061 on `(List<T>)(object)fruits.Apples` as theBigFruitList is a List of Fruits objects and not a Fruits object. Adding .First() in between compiles, but thats not what I'm looking for.